# How to pass next month date using utcnow in adf expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using the below expression in the copy data activity to append current month and year to the filename. I want to pass next month date to the filename(testingfile1220222)

ex:testingfile112022(current month 11 and year 2022)

expected: testingfile122022(next month 12 and year 2022)

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.pipelinepath,'testingfile',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM'),formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'.csv'')/$value/')
```

Comment: how about function getFutureTime(). You might verify if it does what you wan for the end of the month -  Running for today (10/31) results in 11/30.  That function allows you to format it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following dynamic content to build a name for my sample file. It has given the expected output of `testingfile122022.csv`.

- I have used mathematical functions to create dynamic file name. If the month is already equal to `12`, adding one would result in month number as 13. So, to avoid this, I have taken the if condition to avoid this.

```
@concat('testingfile',if(equals(12,int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM'))),'01',string(add(int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'MM')),1))),formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'.csv')
```

[image]

- The pipeline run is successful. It writes a file with the required name. Look at the following image for reference.

[image]

- You can also use the `getFutureTime` **as suggested by @Scott Mildenberger** using the following dynamic content.

```
@concat('testingfile',formatDateTime(getFutureTime(1,'Month'),'MM'),formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy'),'.csv')
```

**NOTE:** I have run this on 1/11/2022.

Comment: Thanks Saideep for your suggestion